# Position in arrays (offset) c#

Tags: c#, arrays, position, offset

I have a problem that i can't solve efficiently.
What I need to do is :
I have a start postion in array(in my case it is list) and I also have an offset.
The offset of type int.: 
[image]

When the offset is > 0 I have this to calculate the new position :

```
        if (currentPosition + offset < lenght)
        {
            return currentPosition + offset;
        }
        return (currentPosition + offset)%lenght;
```

The problem is when the offset < 0 :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < offset * -1; i++)
        {
            currentPosition -= 1;
            if (currentPosition == -1)
            {
                currentPosition = lenght - 1;
            }
        }
        return currentPosition;
```

But this solution is really slow.
Do you guys have an idea.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can offset be large than +7 or smaller than -7? Also, is this always 8-element array or can length vary?

Comment: The lenght of the array can vary and the offset can be more than the array lenght.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with this function, hope it helps (added in-code comments for clarity):

```
private int CalcNewPosition(int[] arr, int position, int offset)
{
    if (position < 0 || position >= arr.Length)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("position");

    // Calculate correct offset that is within bounds of array
    // by using modulus of offset divided by array length.
    var offsetOk = offset % arr.Length;

    // If offset is negative, calculate how many steps to
    // move forward instead of backwards.
    if (offsetOk < 0)
    {
        offsetOk = arr.Length + offsetOk;
    }

    // Calculate new offset
    var result = position + offsetOk;

    // If offset is greater or equal than length of array
    // set it to number of elements from beginning by
    // calculating the difference between length and new offset
    if (result >= arr.Length)
    {
        result = result - arr.Length;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I've tried it with this calls and they all worked (I hope) correctly:

```
var pos1 = CalcNewPosition(arr, 3, 2);
var pos2 = CalcNewPosition(arr, 3, -1);
var pos3 = CalcNewPosition(arr, 3, -56);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you verry much. I did it in my code and it worked like a charm.
Also thank you for the good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `currentPosition` is an integer. So you can just do the calculation, and correct afterwards if it is less then zero;

```
currentPosition = (currentPosition + offset) % lenght;
if (currentPosition<0)
    currentPosition += lenght;
return currentPosition;
```

Answer (score 1):

Given

> (A) 0 < length && length <= int.MaxValue / 3
>    (B) 0 <= position && position < length
>    (C) -length < offset && offset < length

the calculation could be

```
position = (position + offset + length) % length;
```

If the (C) doesn't hold, we can turn it into the same case with `offset % length` and the formula will be instead

```
position = (position + (offset % length) + length) % length;
```

Comment: The limit is actually (int.MaxValue + 2) / 3